# Wait for background video to load completely, then show it

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

Can I & how can I:

- let background video to load
- not show it (with `display` / `visibility` / `z-index` properties ) until loaded
- capture video `loaded` (if exists and reliable!) and change `CSS` properties accordingly so I can show and play background video

The point is that I want to display background video to my users and I'm not willing to ruin user experience of users with modern browsers and low bandwidth - so "wait to download and then play" strategy is my choice - if possible.

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Media API](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#media-elements) that provides you with all you need.

```
var your_video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
your_video.src = 'my_video_' + value + '.ogg';
your_video.load();
```

The Media API also contains a load() method which: "Causes the element to reset and start selecting and loading a new media resource from scratch."

Wait for either the [loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata) or [loadeddata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadeddata) (depending on what you want) events to fire:

```
your_video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
   // your_video is loaded and can be played
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. So I could manually trigger `your_video.load()` to start downloading and I'll get `loadeddata` event video loads completely ?